# React - Configure Store Getting Require not defined error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have created configureStore.dev.js file to configure store for my react-redux app. Below is my code for configureStore.dev.js file.

I am getting "require not defined" error for the "const nextRootReducer = require('../reducers').default;".

How can I rewrite this part to solve the issue?

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import createLogger from 'redux-logger';
import StockApp from '../reducers';
import DevTools from '../containers/DevTools';

const createDevStoreWithMiddleware = compose(
  applyMiddleware(thunk),
  applyMiddleware(createLogger()),
  DevTools.instrument()
)(createStore);

export default function configureStore() {
  const store = createDevStoreWithMiddleware(StockApp);

  // enable webpack hot module replacement for reducers
  if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('../reducers', () => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      const nextRootReducer = require('../reducers').default;
      store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);
    });
  }

  return store;
}
```

Here is my webpack.config.js:

```js
// We are using node's native package 'path'
// https://nodejs.org/api/path.html
const path = require('path');

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

// Constant with our paths
const paths = {
  DIST: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  SRC: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
  JS: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js'),
};

// Webpack configuration
module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(paths.JS, 'app.js'),
  output: {
    path: paths.DIST,
    filename: 'app.bundle.js'
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(paths.SRC, 'index.html'),
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style.bundle.css'),
  ],

  // We are telling webpack to use "babel-loader" for .js and .jsx files
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          'babel-loader',
        ],
      },

      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          use: 'css-loader',
        }),
      },

      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          'file-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },

  // Enable importing JS files without specifying their's extenstion -> ADDED IN THIS STEP
  //
  // So we can write:
  // import MyComponent from './my-component';
  //
  // Instead of:
  // import MyComponent from './my-component.jsx';
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },

  target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  node: {
    console: true,
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
  },

  // Dev server configuration -> ADDED IN THIS STEP
  // Now it uses our "src" folder as a starting point
  devServer: {
    contentBase: paths.SRC,
  },
};
```

Could anyone please help me solve this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you running on _browser_ or _node_ environment? `require` is common module loader function name which is available with _node_; when running on browser you need a loader library like _requirejs_ to get `require()`.

Comment: @DJ. Thank you for your answer. I am running on browser. I have installed requirejs and put in "import require from 'requirejs';" but it still does not work.. Do you know how I can solve this?

Comment: Can you describe how is your project setup at the moment? Does it use a module loader already like `webpack`?

Comment: @DJ. Yes, it does. I have updated my question with my webpack.config.js file. Is there a line that I have to add here?

Answer (score 0):

Hoping that you are using Babel 6+, you can replace this code:

```
const nextRootReducer = require('../reducers').default;
store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);
```

With this:

```
store.replaceReducer('.default')
```

No need to require. Hope it helps.